# MySQL: Join across multiple databases on different computers

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, windows

I am aware that is is possible to do joins across multiple databases but I would like to know if the databases are on different computers is this possible. If this is possible - will the performance suffer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I have used linked servers in MSSQL/SQL-Server before and joining one table to another on a 
different computer can be extremely slow it depends on the data volume.

What I would suggest is that you select data from the remote computer with a appropriate filter into a temp table first. The join this temp table to your local table. This generally speeds things up substantially.